# Installing older version of MySQL 5.5 on Mac OS X with latest version

Tags: mysql, macos, uninstallation, osx-leopard, mysql5

I've installed MySQL 5.5.11 on my new macbook pro.  Unfortunately, I quickly found out MySQL 5.5.11 doesn't fully work on mac os x :(.  MySQL 5.5.8 was the last version that did work.  As a new mac user, what's the proper way to install MySQL 5.5.8?  Can I just install it on top of MySQL 5.5.11?  Should I take certain steps to uninstall 5.5.11?

Also, mysql.com's [page for downloading older versions of 5.5](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.5) has been down all day.  Where can I download 5.5.8?

***UPDATE***: When trying to install MySQL 5.5.8, I get the following error message:

> MySQL 5.5.8-community for Mac OS X
>   can't be installed on this disk.  A
>   newer version of this software already
>   exists on this disk.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, funny, the old releases download website only work once, you have to restart your browser every time you go to another page :-) You can try this: http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.5&v=5.5.8

And you can overwrite the old version.

Comment: Thank you for the proper link!  I'm beginning to be a bit unsure of moving forward with mysql in general..  so if I overwrite v5.5.11 with v5.5.8, will I have any remnants of v5.5.11?  I'd like to remove it completely.

Comment: Where does it install in OSX? like other apps in /Applications/ or in /opt/ like most Unix ports?

Comment: You can't overwrite MySQL 5.5.11 with 5.5.8, see my update to the original question.

Comment: Then it's safe to delete the mysql folder before installing another version. I do that everytime I manually upgrade MySQL on Linux servers and it works like a charm. Since your DBs are located elsewhere (probably /var/lib/mysql/ or something like that) you will never overwrite any DB during a MySQL upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: I finally got it resolved, I had to delete a ton of other files, particularly the receipt files (which are not all in /Library/Receipts).  This wasn't an upgrade, it was a downgrade.  Unfortunately, now I have a problem with MySQL 5.5.8, maybe due to the downgrade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812346/mysql-5-5-8-startup-item-not-working-in-mac-os-x-10-6